# RxJS wait for 2 separate clicks events

Tags: javascript, rxjs, mouseevent, dom-events

I have a button and an image.

When I click the button, I want it to go to a "wait mode" of sorts.
Waiting for two separate clicks, that both return the x, y value of the mouse click events.

I got the mouse xy part no problem but at loss for what RxJS operator to use next

```
const elem = document.getElementById("MyImage");
const root = fromEvent(elem, "click");
const xy = root.pipe(map(evt => xyCartoPos(elem, evt)));
xy.subscribe(coords => console.log("xy:", coords));

function xyCartoPos(elem, e) {
  const elemRect = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: e.clientX - elemRect.x - elemRect.width / 2,
    y: flipNum(e.clientY - elemRect.y - elemRect.height / 2)
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`bufferCount`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/bufferCount) to emit a fixed number of clicks at once (in one array).

```js
const xy = root.pipe(
  map(evt => xyCartoPos(elem, evt)),
  bufferCount(2),
  //take(1) // use take(1) if you only want to emit one pair of clicks and then complete
);
```

Comment: This is really nice! I didn't know about bufferCount.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [scan](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/scan.html) to collect the events as an array, then use [filter](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/filter.html) to verify the length of the array is 2:

```
const xy = root.pipe(
  map(evt => xyCartoPos(elem, evt)),
  scan((acc, evt) => {
    acc.push(evt);
    return acc;
  }, []),
  filter(events => events.length == 2),
);
```

This will cause only an array with the two mouse events, after two clicks, to be published to the subscriber.